# Angular Material Dialog and disabling automatic focus on tabbable element

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material2

The [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content) reads:

> Once a dialog opens, the dialog will automatically focus the first tabbable element.
>
> You can control which elements are tab stops with the tabindex attribute.

I can't see anything in the documentation or configuration options that allows you to completely disable this feature without having to use additional markup on each tabbable element. It seems a little unnecessary and messy.

eg `<p>Contact us on <a href="mailto:email@email.com" tabindex="-1">email@email.com</a></p>`

Is there a configuration option I missing? And if not, I am open to any guidance on how to best approach this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an `autoFocus` attribute that you can set to false on your config that will prevent this from happening. Found it in the [dialog-config source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/25ce323fbceb78392d8468ff6eab67b0b8d717b1/src/material/dialog/dialog-config.ts#L99).

Comment: I would have been/was surprised the developers hadn't thought of it. I'll know take a look at the source code too in future. Thanks!

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143052/how-to-manually-set-focus-on-mat-form-field-in-angular-6 @zmanc

Answer (score 10):

Just to be clear here's an example.

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
    autoFocus: false,
    width: '800px',
    disableClose: true,
    data: { 'data': data}
});
```

Second line (autoFocus: false) will disable the autofocus on dialogs.

You can see more from [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/dialog/dialog-config.ts#L96).